# Restrict Bandwidth by IP

Tags: windows-7, networking, bandwidth, video-streaming, broadband

Is there an easy way to restrict the bandwidth available to a specific range of IPs?

My scenario is I've recently discovered that watching movies on LoveFilm uses a lot more bandwidth than other streaming services (e.g. YouTube, BBC iPlayer) as it defaults to the highest definition available for the connection, rather than allowing me to choose a cap for quality.  This means that it eats through my uage allowance faster than it need.  There are no settings to cap it through the site, so I'm hoping to emulate a worse connection (only for that site).

How can I do this?

Comment: Why the downvote to this question?  There's nothing wrong with the format and there's most certainly an answer to this question...

Comment: @hydroparadise It's a common question on SU.  The typical answer becomes `Google QoS`.

Comment: If it's a common question, perhaps we could mark it as a duplicate instead of simply dismissing it as not constructive. I've taken out the request for a shopping recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [CheckPoint](http://www.checkpoint.com/) router can do what you need it to do.  Very intuitive GUI, very granular as far as control, and allows you to see trafic going through the router in real time in either port of or host view.  [image]